# Can't play League of Legends with PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

Trying to play LOL with 2.8 staging wine and Windows Vista on PlayOnLinux, Ubuntu 17.04.  I watched few YouTube videos to come to this point.  Now, I get the LOL launch screen but when I click on Launch the screen minimizes and no new screen opens.  I can see the new LOL process with "top" but that's it. Any suggestions how to make this work?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=34726 and https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=33303 ... As you can see the test results are for newer Wine versions.

Comment: See https://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: I use Wine2.02 32-bit with XP setting. NOTE: The lolclientrenderUX randomly hangs for an unknown reason. Just end the lolclientUX process and restart. I hang maybe 1 in 10 attempts.